# xcode 4.5 images not displaying in simulator nor device when the @2x version is added

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, tabbar

Im having an issue with images mainly set in storyboard but also by code, the issue is that if there is a @2x version of the file the image wont display neither in the simulator nor in a device, while being perfectly visible in the storyboard.

this issue only happens if there is an @2x file of the version, i have searched for a couple of days and have already checked that the image is set to the target, that the image name and extension case is correct, and that the image is exactly double the size of the low-res file (30x30 original image, 60x60 @2x image), and i´ve read removing the extension when added programmatically will work for targets 4+ but that didn't work either. I have also tried creating new images and cleaning the build, how ever nothing works, I insist, it is not that the low res image is loades, no images is loaded at all, this is noly for when ther is a @2x file in the resources.

something like:

1. both images in resources
2. normal image (not @2x) image set as tab icon in storyboard
3. icons set with @2x counterpart wont show while icons with no @2x image will

(sorry no images, new user and cant post any)

this also happens if the image is set by code whenever the selected image has a @2x

if anyone has any idea of why this is or how i could solve it i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Sounds like the @2x image is actually being selected but something is wrong with the file.

Comment: no, I`ve checked the @2x files (this happens with all images that have an @2x file), I`ve even changed the @2x file´s name and used it as the original image, when I do this, the image shows perfectly (except for the size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the only solution that I found for this issue is to delete the original file (non @2x) and leave the @2x file only en reference the regular file (non @2x) in the code or storyboard

Answer (score 0):

What about the ImageView? Is it in the right visible place? Does any other view overlap your image view?

Comment: the image view is set in the right place, this also happens with the tabbar icons

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 target in your project, may be the image is not in the target you run.

Answer (score 0):

Its more of a photoshop issue than Xcode - Xcode(or simulator n device) does not display all RGB profiles. I've been looking for a solution for hours now and this is what i did.
Open the same size image in photoshop that is accepted(any image that is showing on device).Copy this image over the accepted and flatten layers (it should alert you that RGB profile is being changed), save this result. Now simulator and device shows it. Worked For Me.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the tab bar images in a sub-folder can also cause issue. You should not create a sub-folder to keep images separately, instead create a group in the Xcode project. The issue was solved when I moved my images out of the sub-folder and put them in the root folder of project.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked out when I figured that in Targets -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources -> I did not have the Assets.xcassets added.